# pullback of quotient map: injective on group cohomology?

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, quotient-group, pullback

Let $G$ be a group with normal subgroup $N \triangleleft G$. Let $\pi: G \to G/N$ be the quotient map.

Is the induced map on the group cohomology with coefficients in $U(1)$, i.e., $\pi^*: H^n(G/N,U(1)) \to H^n(G,U(1))$, injective?

(If this is not true in general, is it perhaps true for finite groups or Lie groups?)

Comment: Do you know the answer for $\mathbb Z$-coefficients ?

Comment: @Max I guess that $H^n(G,U(1)) \cong H^n(BG,U(1)) = [BG,K(U(1),n)] = [BG,K(\mathbb Z,n+1)] = H^{n+1}(BG,\mathbb Z)$ $\cong H^{n+1}(G,\mathbb Z)$, is that correct? If so, I agree that it is enough to know the answer for $\mathbb Z$-coefficients, but alas I do not know that either. Apologies if it's trivial; I'm a bit rusty on my cohomology.

Comment: The isomorphism you get is correct at least for finite groups (though I have an algebraic proof for it, rather than going through Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, and I don't know enough to justify how you go from $K(U(1),n)$ to $K(\mathbb Z,n+1)$) . To be fair I can't at the moment think of an example for $\mathbb Z$ although I'm pretty sure there are some

Comment: @Max Thanks for the comments. When you say ``examples for $\mathbb Z$'', do you mean examples which violate the requested property of injectivity of the pullback?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Unfortunately, I only know the $\mathbb Z$-cohomology of very small groups, for bigger groups I know it with torsion coefficients, which is why I have some trouble finding examples. I will come back to you if I find some.

Comment: @Max Do you happen to know $H^4(\mathcal A_4,\mathbb Z)$? Because there is a quotient $\mathcal A_4/\mathcal V \cong \mathbb Z_3$ and $H^4(\mathbb Z_3,\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z_3)$, so if $H^4(\mathcal A_4,\mathbb Z)$ does not have a $\mathbb Z_3$ subgroup, then we're done.

Comment: The problem is that this is split and so in group cohomology injective. That's the issue with small groups : a lot of small extensions are split, and split-ness clearly implies the property you're looking for (by functoriality)

Comment: @Max Good point. I think $G = \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$ and $G/H = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ should do the trick: I think their non-trivial projective representations are incompatible. (Have not yet worked this out.)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z/4\to Z/2}$ does in fact induce an injection on cohomology, and then the Künneth formula should yield an injection on the product, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Oh no ! My bad I had misseen something, it might actually work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not true, even for finite groups. In all that follows, all coefficients will be trivial $G$-modules, and $G$ will be finite.

Firsr of all, note that as groups, $S^1\simeq \mathbb{Q/Z}\oplus V$ where $V$ is some $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. In particular, since $G$ is a finite group, $H^*(G,V)=0$ for $*>0$, so $H^*(G,S^1)\simeq H^*(G,\mathbb{Q/Z})$ for $*>0$.

Then we have a short exact sequence $0\to \mathbb{Z\to Q\to Q/Z}\to 0$ and $H^*(G,\mathbb Q)=0$ for $*>0$ so that $H^*(G,\mathbb{Q/Z}) \simeq H^{*+1}(G,\mathbb Z)$ for $*>0$, all of this being natural in (the finite ) $G$.

So your question becomes (for finite groups) : is $H^*(G/N, \mathbb Z)\to H^*(G,\mathbb Z)$  injective for $*>1$ (knowing that for $*=0$ it trivially is, and for $*=1$ both are $0$ so it is injective too) ?  The answer to that is well-known to be no. As per the comments, here's an example :

Consider $G= C_4\times C_2$ ($C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$) and $G/N = C_2\times C_2$. Then we know that $H^2(C_2,\mathbb Z)\to H^2(C_4,\mathbb Z)$ is multiplication by $2$ from $C_2\to C_4$ and so $H^2(C_2,\mathbb Z)\otimes H^2(C_2,\mathbb Z)\to H^2(C_4,\mathbb Z)\otimes H^2(C_2,\mathbb Z)$ sends $1=  1\otimes 1$ to $2\otimes 1 = 1\otimes 2 = 0$ and in particular isn't injective. By the Künneth formula, it follows that $H^4(C_2\times C_2,\mathbb Z)\to H^4(C_4\times C_2,\mathbb Z)$ is not injective.

Comment: great, thank you!

Comment: Sorry that it took so long, and you're the one to have found the example in the end ! (worse than that : I had considered similar examples, but only in my head and so I told myself "no Künneth implies that it's injective as well" : how stupid of me !)

Answer (score 0):

Max already gave a counter-example, but here is an even simpler one:

Let $G$ be the quaternion group (i.e., the group of order eight generated by $i$, $j$ and $k$ with $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 =-1$). It has no non-trivial projective rep: $H^2(G,U(1))= 0$. However, it has a normal subgroup $N$ generated by $-1$ such that $G/N \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. Since $H^2(\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2,U(1)) = \mathbb Z_2$, it is clear that there exists no injective mapping $$\mathbb Z_2 = H^2(G/N,U(1)) \to H^2(G,U(1)) = 0. $$